# How to schedule AWS App flow using Cloud Formation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-appflow

I have created AWS App flow using cloud formation template and I want to schedule an app flow using Trigger Config.
How can we pass date ScheduleStartTime using cloud formation?

**Error I'm getting**

> AWS::AppFlow::FlowCreate Flow request failed:
> [Schedule start time cannot be in the past. Please update the schedule
> start time to a value in future.

The snippet I'm using in cloud formation,

```
"TriggerConfig": {
          "TriggerType": "Scheduled",
          "TriggerProperties": {
            "DataPullMode": "Incremental",
            "ScheduleExpression": "rate(5minutes)",
            "TimeZone": "America/New_York",
            "ScheduleStartTime" : 4.05
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TriggerConfig:
         TriggerType: Scheduled
         TriggerProperties:
              DataPullMode: Incremental
              ScheduleExpression: rate(1days)
              ScheduleStartTime: 1652970600
```

Use Unix timestamp for start time.
Please refer to the below link for conversion.
https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: as per AWS documentation, ScheduleStartTime must be in ISO 8601 format, like 2022-04-26T13:00:00-07:00

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-appflow-flow-scheduledtriggerproperties.html#cfn-appflow-flow-scheduledtriggerproperties-scheduleexpression

Answer (score 0):

try ScheduleInterval parameter instead of  ScheduleExpression

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).